# Webpack's CommonChunksPlugin configuration with lazy loaded modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nativescript

I'm using Webpack with  `CommonChunksPlugin` .

My problem is with lazy loaded modules.
When I load lazy modules ( `0.js` and `1.js` in image) , Where each  uses the `Http Module`  , it seems that `Http` is embedded/repeated in EACH module :

The entries in my file are  :

```
 entry: {
            bundle: aot ? "./main.aot.ts" : "./main.ts",
            vendor: "./vendor",
        },
```

**With CommonsChunkPlugin configured as :**

> ```
>  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
>             name: ["vendor"],
>         }),
> ```

— I get [*this result*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e0NV.jpg) where you can see multiple http.js both in bundle & 1.js& 0.js.

[image]

**With CommonsChunkPlugin configured with `async`** ( as written in [here](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-bits-getting-the-most-out-of-the-commonschunkplugin-ab389e5f318#f678)) :

> ```
>  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
>            async: true, 
>            children: true, 
>
>         }),
> ```

— I get  [*this result*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Zle.jpg)  where you can see tha `0.js` and `1.js` are OK but the `bundle.js` now contains dups as vendor(?!?!)

[image]

**Question:**

I've read the [*docs*](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) But as you can see , I'm trying to do something without success.

How can I fix the config  so that common chunks will be extracted and not be repeated ?

[**webpack.config**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/da35cb88252018422327663e0f14a942)

Comment: do you use angular cli?

Comment: Looks like what you need is CommonChunksPlugin, this will help you to extract out modules/chunks which are common across other chunks and create another chunk. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

Comment: @Arjun I've already tried using it but it doubles the size of the bundle and doesn't extract the common. The image in the question is AFTER using this plugin.

Comment: Can you try adding `minChunks:2` to commonChunks plugin options. this means if the module is found 2 or more chunks it will be moved to a separate chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue as you are/were facing.
In my case, I've removed the name parameter from the configuration and set `async` to true and children to true as well.
Also, make sure that the `CommonChunksPlugin` is the last plugin in the array of plugins.